# Drupal How to fix notice unserialize() and Undefined index?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am getting below mention notice on /admin/reports/status page.

1. Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 728 bytes in field_read_fields() (line 374 of /my_website/modules/field/field.crud.inc).
2. Notice: Undefined index: settings in text_field_schema() (line 17 of /my_website/modules/field/modules/text/text.install).

How to fix the notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function unserialize() fails to convert a serialized value back into a PHP value because of an invalid length (or a length mismatch) in the stored representation of the data.

This means that a field record was not stored correctly in its field table.

The second notice tells us the type of the incriminated field : `text_field_schema()`, invoked via the `hook_field_schema`, exposes three field types : `text`, `text_long`, `text_with_summary`.

```
// line 392 of modules/field/field.crud.inc
$schema = (array) module_invoke($field['module'], 'field_schema', $field);
```

Just above, line 388, you got this :

```
module_invoke_all('field_read_field', $field);
```

By implementing this hook you should be able to point out which record is broken :

```
function yourmodule_field_read_field($field) {
  if ($field['module'] === 'text' && !isset($field['settings'])) {
    dpm($field);
  }
}
```

Once identified, you will probably have to "repair" the field structure before saving it as usual via FieldAPI, e.g. :

```
$field += array(
  'settings' => array(
    'max_length' => $somelength
  )
);
field_update_field($field);
```

The structure should be as defined in [field_create_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7.x).

---

[EDIT]

If you can't use field API, still you should be able to see which record is broken for that field.

Call `field_read_field($field_name)` and debug :

```
// line 370 of modules/field/field.crud.inc
$fields = array();
$results = $query->execute();
foreach ($results as $record) {
  dpm($record); // check $record['data']
  $field = unserialize($record['data']); 
  // ...
}
```

The broken record should be printed just before the first notice (if you display it).

Check the serialized value (`$record['data']`), and compare it with other records to see what's wrong. In the end you may have to update the field using SQL statements if you can't use field API.

Comment: implemented 
function yourmodule_field_read_field($field) {
  if ($field['module'] === 'text' && !isset($field['settings'])) {
    dpm($field);
  }
} but showing nothing.

Comment: I also replace yourmodule with my custom module name.

Comment: You should see the dpm() output when going at /admin/reports/status. Or I miss something... Maybe change the condition. I will recheck later I come back in 2 hours

Comment: that is showing when after cache-clear. I get the field for which this is coming. "field_why"

Comment: This field is inside field_collection. So when calling field_update_field($field); the site stop and show timeout.

Comment: Ok, the field is identified, so now you should be able to see which record is broken for that field, check the serialized value (`$record['data']`), and compare it with other records to see what's wrong. In the end you may have to update the field using SQL statements if you can't use field API.

Comment: Yes, I check the value of $record['data'] for that field. The serialize data was not correct. I updated the data with new one and it works. Thank you @Eric

Comment: can you explain why the data get broken?

Comment: @Mahtab It may be because someone edited the stored representation of the data into the database, or maybe that the `data` field itself has not the proper type to store your values in database. PHP says `serialize()` returns a string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field. You may want to check this.